# Check hash values before pushing to an array in perl

Tags: perl

For creating a Json file i am pushing a hashes in an array but the values are getting duplicated now i don't want to add those hashes which are already in the array.

```
foreach my $corp_id(@{corpId}) {
    foreach my $rcode(@{$brands_map->{$corp_id->{s_brand}}}) {
            my corpIdAccessCode;
            $corpIdAccessCode->{accessCode} = $corp_id->{s_id};
            $corpIdAccessCode->{corporateId} = $corp_id->{c_id};
            $corpIdAccessCode->{bcode} = $rcode;
            push @{$accessCode_array} ,$corpIdAccessCode; **// Here before pushing to array i want to have a check wheather $corp_id->{s_id}, $corp_id->{c_id} and  $rcode already exists or not in the accessCode_array**
    }
}
```

So from the below array of hashes i don't want  duplicate ones

```
[
      {
        "accessCode": "NQ",
        "bcode": "PD",
        "corporateId": "12"
      },
      {
        "accessCode": "NQ",
        "bcode": "CI",
        "corporateId": "2122121"
      },
      {
        "accessCode": "NQ",
        "bcode": "CI",
        "corporateId": "2122121"
      },
      {
        "accessCode": "CD",
        "bcode": "PD",
        "corporateId": "12"
      },
```

The final ooutput from the code changes should give a result like below :

```
[
      {
        "accessCode": "NQ",
        "bcode": "PD",
        "corporateId": "12"
      },
      {
        "accessCode": "NQ",
        "bcode": "CI",
        "corporateId": "2122121"
      },

      {
        "accessCode": "CD",
        "bcode": "PD",
        "corporateId": "12"
      },
```

Or is there any way we can remove duplicate hashes from the array.

Comment: Is `my $corpIdaccessCode;` a transcription error, or actually in the code?

Comment: Do those hashes have any uniq field or you need to check all fields?

Comment: @jhnc i have updated the question sorry for confusion

Comment: @UjinT34 before pushing to the array i want to check all three hash keys values exists in the array or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking `!$seen{$key}++` is a common way of identifying the first of duplicates. For example,

```
my %seen;
my @uniques = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @items;
```

This can be unrolled into a foreach loop.

```
my %seen;
for my $corp_id (@corpId) {
    for my $rcode (@{ $brands_map->{ $corp_id->{s_brand} } }) {
        next if $seen{ $corp_id->{s_id} }{ $corp_id->{c_id} }{ $rcode }++;

        push @$accessCode_array, {
            accessCode  => $corp_id->{s_id},
            corporateId => $corp_id->{c_id},
            bcode       => $rcode,
        };
    }
}
```

To save memory, you could even replace

```
next if $seen{ $corp_id->{s_id} }{ $corp_id->{c_id} }{ $rcode }++;
```

with

```
next if $seen{ join ":", $corp_id->{s_id}, $corp_id->{c_id}, $rcode }++;
```

but that assumes none of the three fields can contain `:`.

Comment: I would write something like this myself but postfix conditionals and `++` are considered to be a bad style. `$seen{ $corp_id->{s_id} }{ $corp_id->{c_id} }{ $rcode }++` is hard to read. And using a delimeter is a bit unreliable.

Comment: @UjinT34, Re "*considered to be a bad style.*", Quite that contrary, `!$seen{$_}++` is an idiom, so it can't possibly be bad style. It also means that deviations are harder to read by virtue of being departures from the usual.

Comment: @UjinT34, Re "*And using a delimeter is a bit unreliable.*", huh?

Comment: @ikegami He is probably referring to the Perl Best Practices suggestion reflected in https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::ControlStructures::ProhibitPostfixControls. (I completely disagree with this opinion/policy.) I'm not sure who considers `++` bad style.

Comment: @UjinT34 postfix ++ for uniqifying is a pretty universal idiom.  doing `++$seen{...} == 1` instead of `!$seen{...}++` might be considered more readable I guess, but I think that ship has long sailed.

Comment: As I mentioned I prefer the approach from this answer myself. I just don't want to recommend it for everyone. With `++` in a conditional you have too keep in mind what happens first: increment or evaluation. A lot of coders get confused with such relatively simple constructions.

Comment: @UjinT34, Actually, you don't. You just need to know that `!$seen{$_}++` finds the first of duplicates (and that `$seen{$_}++` finds everything else). Knowing how it works is secondary.

Answer (score 1):

It would be ineficient to check the whole array before pushing or remove duplicates afterwards. So you need to keep track what data you have pushed already:

```
my $seen;
foreach my $corp_id(@{corpId}) {
    foreach my $rcode(@{$brands_map->{$corp_id->{s_brand}}}) {
            my ($k1, $k2, $k3) = ($corp_id->{s_id}, $corp_id->{c_id}, $rcode);
            if ($seen->{$k1}->{$k2}->{$k3}) {
                next;
            }
            $seen->{$k1}->{$k2}->{$k3} = 1;

            my $corpIdAccessCode;
            $corpIdAccessCode->{accessCode} = $corp_id->{s_id};
            $corpIdAccessCode->{corporateId} = $corp_id->{c_id};
            $corpIdAccessCode->{bcode} = $rcode;
            push @{$accessCode_array} ,$corpIdAccessCode; **// Here before pushing to array i want to have a check wheather $corp_id->{s_id}, $corp_id->{c_id} and  $rcode already exists or not in the accessCode_array**
    }
}
```

`my ($k1, $k2, $k3)` just to make it shorter and more readable.